# Update button cannot function

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2016-localdb

I'm a VB.NET programmer. I have created an update web form in ASP.NET having 3 fields; `ID`, `Names`, `Email` with 3 buttons `cmdUpdate`, `cmdDelete` and `cmdCancel`. All are executing except for the update button which is not executing, and I can't get an error message either. The code is below.

```
Protected Sub cmdUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdate.Click
    Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=RegDb_backend;Integrated security=true;")
    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE tblClients SET ClientNames=@Names, ClientEmail=@Email WHERE ClientID=@ID;"
    Dim cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Names", txtNames.Text.Trim()))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim()))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", Convert.ToInt64(txtID.Text.Trim)))

    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        lblSuccess.Visible = True
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I have tried researching and tweaking around with the code but the database won't get updated. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: can you please post aspx code here.

Comment: Check Connection string ?

Comment: If it's asp.net, don't display message in MsgBox, let it throw the error normally. Also, does it actually execute the code?

Comment: But the same connection string is working for other codeBehind procedures.

Comment: Could be a lot of things: Connection string is off, improper permissions on the account executing the SQL, something in your front end html that isn't allowing a postback or many other things. Put a breakpoint and step through the code, put a break point at the exception, if there is an exception it will hit it and you can hover over it and see what it says. Also, MSGBOX() only posts to your personal computer in Visual Studio, it is not appropriate for actual released cod, just an FYI.

Comment: Thanks. Lemme try.

Comment: You should close the connection in a finally statement. Curently, if an error occurs the connection is left open.